# Javascript image change from multiple list select

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, select

Trying to figure out how to change the main image on a product from a couple of small swatch images. The main product is made of of two parts, front and back, and would like the main image to show the combination of the two.

So for example:

```
<img id="main-image">

<div id="front">
<img src="/red_thumb.jpg">
<img src="/green_thumb.jpg>
</div>

<div id="back">
<img src="/blue_thumb.jpg">
<img src="/black_thumb.jpg">
</div>
```

Then when you select green from the #front and blue from the #back it would change the URL for the #main-image src to "/green-blue.jpg"

I can get this working with select drop downs, but would prefer lists or images so I could do small swatch images that could be selected instead. Would I need to have a select that is hidden and controlled by the image clicks?

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide your javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

you can start by trying following code.
The whole point to give below solution is to make you aware that you can use **jquery.data** to accomplish this task. let me know if you need any more info.

I will also suggest to go through following documentation.
[jQuery Data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

```
<img id="main-image">

<div id="front">
<img src="/red_thumb.jpg" data-image-path="IMAGE_PATH" class="img-thumb">
<img src="/green_thumb.jpg"  data-image-path="IMAGE_PATH" class="img-thumb">
</div>

<div id="back">
<img src="/blue_thumb.jpg"  data-image-path="IMAGE_PATH" class="img-thumb">
<img src="/black_thumb.jpg"  data-image-path="IMAGE_PATH" class="img-thumb">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $(".img-thumb").click(function(){
     var imgPath = $(this).data("image-path");
     $(".main-image").attr("src",imgPath);
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect opportunity for the "data" attribute. Try this:

**Html**

```
<img id="main-image">

<div id="front">
<img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/phobia/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20161109225243" data-color="red" data-side="front" class="img-thumb">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/eucAMTA.jpg" data-color="green" data-side="front" class="img-thumb">
</div>

<div id="back">
<img src="http://www.drodd.com/images14/blue22.jpg" data-color="blue" data-side="back" class="img-thumb">
<img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" data-color="black" data-side="back" class="img-thumb">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var backcolor = "";
var frontcolor = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img.img-thumb').click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('side') && $(this).data('color')) {
      if ($(this).data('side') == "front") {
        frontcolor = $(this).data('color');
      } else {
        backcolor = $(this).data('color');
      }
    }
    if (backcolor && frontcolor) {
      var imgUrl = "/" + frontcolor + "-" + backcolor + ".jpg";
      $('#main-image').attr("src", "/" + backcolor + "_" + frontcolor + ".jpg");
    }
  });
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/xqnq2cgz/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and ask for explanation if you need some.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#back, #front').find('img').on('click', function(e){
    $target = $( e.target );
    var color = $target.attr('src').match(/\/(.+)_.*/)[1];

    console.log(color);

    $target.parent()
         .find('img')
       .removeClass('active');

    $target.addClass('active');

    $target.siblings('img:not(.active)')
         .css('background-color', '');

    $target.css('backgroundColor', color);
    
    if( $('#back .active').length && $('#back .active').length ){
      var back  = $('#back .active').attr('src').match(/\/(.+)_.*/)[1];
      var front = $('#front .active').attr('src').match(/\/(.+)_.*/)[1];

      var mainImg = 'http://brewerybranding.com/apparel/tshirts-new/' 
                  + front + '-' 
                  + back + '.jpg';

      $('#main-image').attr('src', mainImg);      
      console.log(mainImg);
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.example {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#main-image, #front img, #back img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  <img id="main-image">

  <div id="front">
    <img src="/red_thumb.jpg">
    <img src="/green_thumb.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id="back">
    <img src="/blue_thumb.jpg">
    <img src="/black_thumb.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Question on the urls. If my thumbnail URLs aren't in a root folder like /red.jpg, how do I edit the script to combine them. For example, the thumbs are in domain.com/images/newhat/red.jpg, so when I'm using this script I'm getting domain.com/images/newhat/red-domain.com/newhat/green.jpg, how is that new URL constructed? Thanks!

Comment: You can improve it with "var mainImg" edit or we can extend it as function which take "prefix" to the url you want to add. Where will you store url base?

mainImg = 'http://google.com/images/' + mainImg

after "var mainImage" and you've changed it.

Comment: Ok, so that line should read like: var mainImg = 'domain.com/images/' + front + '-' + back + '.jpg';

Comment: Don't forget "http://" or "https://" prefix. This is url requirement for image "src" attribute. If you nedd I can expand my aswer with real url example.

Comment: Ok, I'm still getting the whole URL doubling up. Do I need to change the var front and var back as well?   Here is the page I'm working on: http://brewerybranding.com/apparel/tshirts-new/

Comment: I've made code edit. Now your website is working with error but link looks right.

Comment: I think the issue might be my thumbnails aren't in the root folder, they are in /images/newhat/, so how do I remove that part of the url from each. I've updated the page so you can see what it's generating. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Solved it, thanks so much for the help! I actually combined two of the fixes on this page and got the URLs working correctly. Thanks!